# Is there a callback to know when the submitted page returns when using jquery submit() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

In my page I have a button to do an Excel export.

I need to do a POST so that I can receive the data in the server so I am doing this:

```
                    var newForm = jQuery('<form>', {
                        'method': 'post',
                        'action': targetUrl,
                        'target': '_top'
                    }).append(jQuery('<input>', {
                        'name': 'Search',
                        'value': toSearch,
                        'type': 'hidden'
                    }).append(jQuery('<input>', {
                        'name': 'cargaId',
                        'value': $('#CargaId').val(),
                        'type': 'hidden'
                    })));

                    newForm.appendTo('body').submit().remove();
```

The fact is that I need to show a waiting message while the page is processing, and hide the message when the page returns.

Is there a way?

thanks
Jaime

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way in javascript to accomplish this without the use of ajax or any other method for posting the form via javascript.

Here's an example on how to act on response on a form submit with jquery [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```
$('#form').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: $('#form').attr('action'),
      type: 'POST',
      data : $('#form').serialize(),
      success: function(){
        // Do what you want here. 
      }
    });
    return false;
});
```